# Converter aplicativo VB6 para WebForms C# com Entity

Tags: c#, webforms, visual-basic-6

Tenho uma aplicação em `VB 6` e gostaria de migrá-la para `WebForms` utilizando de preferencia `c#` com `entity`.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta que me ajude nesta conversão(migração).

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262950/CodeConverter

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar essas ferramentas de conversão de código para auxiliar em algumas  unidades de código no processo de migração. Contudo, no passado você não tinha os recursos que tem hoje.

As ferramentas de conversão não vão te dar um código com os padrões da atualidade, otimização, nomenclatura adequada e outras facetas da Orientação a Objetos, coisa que o VB6 não é.